# Writing to SQLite3 on iPhone simulation

Tags: iphone, database, persistence, sqlite, simulator

I have an app that is running in the simulator. I read and write from a sqlite3 data source. However, if i restart the app, then all datg that i had previously wrote to the db is lost.
The data is always in its original state.

Now back when i was developing this app i thought i read somewhere that data can not be persisted via iphone simulator.

Can anybody confirm or deny this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to place your db file in a writable place, e.g. in the `Documents` folder.  All the bundle files are read-only files.

If you are distributing an initial database with the app, you will need to copy it to `Documents` (or another folder) and use the copy.

You also need to ensure that you close the database connection in your application is closing (i.e. you receive a `applicationWillTerminate` message).

Comment: Thanks.

I am copying to the documents folder. but im not certain if im closing the db properly. Let try this out and see what happens.

Comment: OK. the only place i call sqlite3_close is when i have an error with the db initialization stuff. In my applicationWillTerminate message, the only thing i do is update all data entities to the db if they are dirty. Other than that, im not closing the db after that. Should i be?

is it simply sqlite3_close(db)?

Comment: are you sure that you don't override your writable database everytime?

Comment: yes, im sure. database is owned by the app delegate. each data entity in my model has a reference to it.

each of my transaction functions, such as createData, has a sqlite3_prepare_v2 statement and ultimately a sqlite3_reset statement.

None of these functions have a sqlite3_close or a sqlite3_finalize.
The only function that has both of the statements is in my initDatabase function (in the appdelegate) which also calls sqlite3_open.

Comment: msaeed, i didnt think this was the case, but based on a NSLog i just put in, it seems you are right! I am re-writing the database. in other words, the code to detect whether it exists is not working!

Comment: Wow. i actually had code that said "if it exists, delete it". Case solved, i hope.